# Corollary "to" vs "of"

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct: "The corollary to something" or "The corollary of something"?
Or are they both correct?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, both are correct, but I prefer "corollary to" because of nothing more tangible than personal taste.